# Is there a function that can scale a summation to a specific range.

Tags: functions

We are currently working with a scoring system where we want to combine individual scores out of 0-100 without exceeding 100.

For example: Score 1 = 70, Score 2 = 70, Combined score should be aprox = 80.

Example 2: Score 1= 70, Score 2 = 70, Score 3 = 70 , Combined score should be aprox = 85.

If we add more number of scores, then it should affect the combined score positively, but again, make sure not exceed 100.

Comment: Why should combined scores be 80, 85?  Why not 70, 70?

Comment: clarify your requirements. what should be 70,70,70,70? This is vague. I don't see a definite pattern. What should be 60,70,70, for instance?

Comment: the problem is you ask for *a* function. It is possible to make *infinite* functions, but only some would suit your needs. Your question, as it stands now, hasn't clarified those needs.

Comment: For 70, 70, 70, 70 it should be slightly more than 70, 70, 70. Consider a point that has a score out of 100. If that point has neighbors, then it should get a boost in the score. So if a point has score 70, and it has two neighbors with 70 score each, then it should get a boost more than it would if it had one neighbor. We know it's vague, we are trying to find a family of functions to suit our needs. The exact values don't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I will work with $[0,1]$ in the following. you can do the transfer to $[0,100]$ yourself)

There are infinitely many functions that satify your needs. As I understand it, you are looking for a function that might be defined as follows.

Let $x,y\in[0,1]$ then
$$\begin{align}
f(x,y) &= f(y,x) \\
f(0,y) &= y \\
f(x,y) &> x \quad\text{for }\, y>0 \\
f(x,y) &\in[0,1]
\end{align}$$

A simple way to get such a function is to choose an invertible function $g:[0,\infty]\mapsto[0,1]$ and use the usual summation in $\mathbb{R}$ to define 
$$ f(x,y) = g(g^{-1}(x)+g^{-1}(y)). $$

For example: $g(x) = \tanh(x)$ gives $f(x,y) = \tanh(\tanh^{-1}(x)+\tanh^{-1}(y))$ which will never exceed $1$ but might be a bit too steep for you ($f(0.7, 0.7) \approx 0.93$). You can scale it by introducing an exponent $n$ as
$$ f(x,y) = \left(\tanh(\tanh^{-1}(x^n)+\tanh^{-1}(y^n))\right)^{1/n}. $$

For $n=5$ this will be very close to the examples you chose. $f(0.7,0.7)\approx0.80$, $f(f(0.7,0.7),0.7) \approx f(0.8, 0.7) \approx 0.86$.

If this still does not suite your needs you have to choose another $g$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its a start. Can u give me examples for a few more g functions?